# Does anybody know a Remote Desktop alternative for W10 that works through LAN besides Windows Remote Dektop, available for Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, 19.10, remote-desktop, lan

I'm using Windows Home, and it doesn't include WRD; and I tried to activate it but it is still not working; so, is there any alternative to a remote desktop that **works through LAN**?
I'm using Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and tried to use a remote desktop, but the #stayathome made the internet horribly slow, and so I need a solution through LAN.

Comment: Can you explain "works through LAN"? I'm not sure what that has to do with remote desktop.  I use Reminna btw

Comment: I mean, connected in the same WIFI; not a connection through the internet.

Comment: Try Reminna. It has the option to connect to RDP through an ip and port

Comment: I know. But my W10 home edition DOES NOT HAVE Remote Desktop Enabled

Comment: So this is a question about W10 - Windows 10 - which is off topic here.

Comment: Not necesarily. I'm looking for a LAN remote desktop that works with Ubuntu and W10
I've already know some options for LAN remote desktop for W10, but they're not to be used from Ubuntu

Comment: Have you looked at these two resouces? https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-reminna-and-using-rdp-with-windows10-home/ and https://remmina.org/remmina-on-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you looked at these two resouces? linuxliteos.com/forums/tutorials/… and remmina.org/remmina-on-windows

Was suggested by Graham in the comments, this is what I was looking for.